# background image for kendochart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I am trying to set a background image for the kendo chart looking at the code for the demo website here:http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/line-charts/index.html

however I am not able to get the same results for a bubble chart.
eg code here:
http://jsbin.com/alupin/42/edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed:

```
chartArea: {
    background: ""
},
```

In `kendoChart` initialization.